# Laravel job batch: PendingDispatch::__invoke() does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

When processing a job batch, when it goes to the next job and finishes it is throwing a reflection exception. You can find my [exception details](https://flareapp.io/share/DPyZ0lQ7) on Flare.

I've seen other posts about Reflection exceptions, so I've tried

- Restarting valet
- `composer update`
- `composer dump-autoload`

My job is dispatched using the following code:

```
$batch = Bus::batch(
    $this->sisProvider()
        ->syncSchools()
        ->filter(fn (School $school) => $school->active)
        ->map(fn (School $school) => SyncSchool::dispatch($school))
)->then(function (Batch $batch) {
    $this->notifySyncEmails(TenantSyncComplete::class);
})->catch(function (Batch $batch, \Throwable $ex) {
    $this->notifySyncEmails(TenantSyncFailed::class);
})->finally(function (Batch $batch) {
    $this->update(['batch_id' => null]);
})->name('Tenant SIS Sync')->dispatch();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was how the batch was built. Calling `SyncSchool::dispatch($school)` dispatches that job independently and returns a `PendingDispatch`. So a `PendingDispatch` was put in the batch, not my desired `SyncSchool` job.

Changing `SyncSchool::dispatch($school)` in my map to `new SyncSchool($school)` correctly puts the `SyncSchool` job in the batch.

Lesson: read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#dispatching-batches) closely.